# Connecting to the Gmail API from a headless server without graphical Oauth password box?

Tags: java, gmail

I'm trying to use Google's Gmail API to automate the retrieval of certain information that due to hard requirements can only be delivered via email. I've successfully been able to pick up messages, but Gmail demands that I authenticate using a graphical, web-based password box. Obviously this is unacceptable for use in a headless scenario where graphical web browsers are unavailable. I've been scouring the documentation but I can't seem to find a way around this. I'm using Java for this purpose, with a view to converting it to Kotlin to match the rest of the codebase.

My first thought was to bodge this by using Selenium and geckodriver to click the box in a virtual browser every time the API wanted re-authentication but this seems a bit ugly as well as potentially causing outages (IIRC geckodriver takes a while to spin up). Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you considered going though the SMTP server directly?  Unfortunately  unless this is a gsuite domain account the only way for you to use the Gmail api would be to use Oauth2 for authorization.

Comment: @DaImTo, I'll have to look into that, cheers for your reply.